# Automapper says Mapper.Map is obsolete, global mappings?

Tags: c#, automapper

I had defined in my project a global Automapper configuration that would allow me to use `Mapper.Map<targetType>(sourceObject);` in my code. (See my configuration below.)

I updated the NuGet package, and I see the message that Mapper.Map is obsolete/depreciated. I went back to Automapper on GitHub and see examples like this:

```
[Test]
public void Example()
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Source1, SubDest1>().FixRootDest();
        cfg.CreateMap<Source2, SubDest2>().FixRootDest();
    });

    config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    var subDest1 = mapper.Map<Source1, SubDest1>(new Source1 {SomeValue = "Value1"});
    var subDest2 = mapper.Map<Source2, SubDest2>(new Source2 {SomeOtherValue = "Value2"});

    subDest1.SomeValue.ShouldEqual("Value1");
    subDest2.SomeOtherValue.ShouldEqual("Value2");
}
```

Am I going to have to create a configuration in EVERY method that uses a mapping?

My current global configuration:

```
namespace PublicationSystem.App_Start
{
    public class AutoMapperConfig
    {
        public static void CreateMaps()
        {
            CreateProjectMaps();
        }

        private static void CreateProjectMaps()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Project, ProjectCreate>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Project, ProjectSelectable>();
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

***UPDATE:*** Thanks to some coaching from Scott Chamberlain I have created a class like this:

```
    public class MkpMapperProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
    {
        protected override void Configure() 
        {
            this.CreateMap<Project, ProjectCreate>();

            this.CreateMap<Project, ProjectSelectable>();

            this.CreateMap<Project, ProjectDetails>();

            // Many Many other maps
        }
    }
```

I'm thinking I should have the 'MapperConfiguration' in my BaseController class. I started to do something like this:

```
public partial class BaseController : Controller
{

    private MapperConfiguration mapConfig;

    public BaseController()
    {
        db = new MkpContext();
        SetMapperConfig();
    }

    private void SetMapperConfig()
    {
        mapConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile<MkpMapperProfile>();
            });
    }

    public BaseController(MapperConfiguration config)
    {
        db = new MkpContext();
        this.mapConfig = config;
    }
}
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Automapper is moving away from globally scoped static functions. This allows libraries written by different authors to use AutoMapper without interfering with each other.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means for me. I'm getting bits of information here and there, but it's not making a complete picture for me. I've read this: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Migrating-from-static-API but it's not making sense. Do I need to define a config in EVERY ActionResult that uses AutoMapper? I could move it to a datalayer... And My app doesn't seem to have `MvcApplication.MapperConfiguration`. Where is that defined?

Comment: You make one, basicly create a class that derives from `Profile`, override the `Configure()`  function, then paste in your `CreateProjectMaps` but replace `Mapper.` with `this.`

Comment: My app has a class called `Profile`. I'm assuming you mean a `Profile` from the AutoMapper namespace? Details like that help make things less ambiguous.

Comment: `MvcApplication.MapperConfiguration` in your example would be `AutoMapperConfig.MapperConfiguration`, you would need to add a `public static MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration {get; set;}` to the class and assign a value to it like they do in the example you linked to. the `MvcApplication` is not somthing built in, they where using it as a placeholder name for ***your*** MvcApplication.

Comment: @MKenyonII I'm putting *some* of the static API back in. You'll have Mapper.Map and Mapper.Initialize. But no Mapper.CreateMap, that was too buggy. Continue on.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is how I've handled it.

Create maps in a Profile, taking care to use the Profile's CreateMap method rather than Mapper's static method of the same name:

```
internal class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Project, ProjectCreate>();
    }
}
```

Then, wherever dependencies are wired-up (ex: Global.asax or Startup), create a MapperConfiguration and then use it to create an IMapper.

```
var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
    });
```

Then, use the configuration to generate an IMapper:

```
var mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
```

Then, register that mapper with the dependency builder (I'm using Autofac here)

```
builder.RegisterInstance(mapper).As<IMapper>();
```

Now, wherever you need to map stuff, declare a dependency on IMapper:

```
internal class ProjectService : IProjectService {
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public ProjectService(IMapper mapper) {
         _mapper = mapper;
    }
    public ProjectCreate Get(string key) {
        var project = GetProjectSomehow(key);
        return _mapper.Map<Project, ProjectCreate>(project);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that in AutoMapper 5.0 the MappingProfile confi is just handled in the constructor. No need to override anymore.

Answer (score 14):

I'm using version 5.2.0, support to create maps in constructors instead of override configure.

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Project, ProjectDto>();
    }
}
```

In Global.asax.cs call like:

```
Mapper.Initialize(c=>c.AddProfile<MappingProfile>());
```

Hope this help.

Comment: If you need to add profiles dynamically  `Mapper.Initialize(c => c.AddProfiles(new string[] { "DLL_NAME" }));`

Answer (score 7):

This is new in AutoMapper 4.2. There is a blog post by Jimmy Bogard on this: [Removing the static API from AutoMapper](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/01/21/removing-the-static-api-from-automapper/). It claims that

> The IMapper interface is a lot lighter, and the underlying type is now just concerned with executing maps, removing a lot of the threading problems...

The new syntax: (pasted from the blog post)

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
  cfg.CreateMap<User, UserDto>();
});
```

---

If you just want the "old way" of doing this. The latest **version 4.2.1** has brought back some tradition. Just use

```
CreateMap<Project, ProjectCreate>();
```

instead of

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Project, ProjectCreate>();
```

The old code will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can find configured AutoMapper 4.2 in my ASP.NET MVC Template project here: https://github.com/NikolayIT/ASP.NET-MVC-Template

1. Create these classes: https://github.com/NikolayIT/ASP.NET-MVC-Template/tree/master/ASP.NET%20MVC%205/Web/MvcTemplate.Web.Infrastructure/Mapping
2. Annotate view models with `IMapFrom<>`: https://github.com/NikolayIT/ASP.NET-MVC-Template/blob/master/ASP.NET%20Core/Web/AspNetCoreTemplate.Web/ViewModels/Settings/SettingViewModel.cs
3. Use it as `.To<SomeViewModel>()`. Example: https://github.com/NikolayIT/ASP.NET-MVC-Template/blob/master/ASP.NET%20MVC%205/Web/MvcTemplate.Web/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L27

Comment: These links do not exist any more?

Answer (score 1):

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>();
});
```