# How to automap a list to another list

Tags: c#, wpf, automapper

using automapper in my c# wpf dekstop app.

I have these 2 models:

```
public class A
{
    public string Field1 {get; set;}
    public string Field2 {get; set;}
}

public class B
{
    public string Field1 {get; set;}
    public string Field2 {get; set;}
}
```

I create a collection of Class A by populating via a db query so:

```
list<A> collectionA = DB.GetQueryResults();
```

I now want to 'transfer' this collection to Class B by using AutoMapper..

```
var configJobProfile = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<A, B>());
var mapperJobProfile = configJobProfile.CreateMapper(); 
collectionB = mapperJobProfile.Map<B>(collectionA);
```

But i get a mapping error which doe snot tell me much. So I assuming this approach is wrong?

How should I do this?

Thanks

Screen-[image]Shot of Deprecated function:

Comment: What is the mapping error? See inner exception.

Answer (score 2):

You have set up a mapping from A -> B, but the map you are trying to perform is for a List of As -> List of Bs.

Set up a mapping for the lists and that should do the trick i.e.

```
var configJobProfile = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<List<A>, List<B>>());
var mapperJobProfile = configJobProfile.CreateMapper();
List<B> collectionB = mapperJobProfile.Map<List<B>>(collectionA);
```

Comment: thanks, i did do this before (i thought i had!) and it produced an error. This time time no error but no records even though I know there IS 1 record. Will continue to investigate - thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using AutoMapper;

public class Foo
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }  
}

public class Bar
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }  
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()       
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Foo,Bar>();

        var foo = new Foo { A="test", B=100500 };

        var bar = Mapper.Map<Bar>(foo);

        Console.WriteLine("foo type is {0}", foo.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("bar type is {0}", bar.GetType());

        Console.WriteLine("foo.A={0} foo.B={1}", foo.A, foo.B);
        Console.WriteLine("bar.A={0} bar.B={1}", bar.A, bar.B);
    }
}
```

Here is link to the [Tutorial](https://dotnetcademy.net/Learn/2/Pages/2)

About depricated warning check answer of @Romi Petrelis [Automapper says Mapper.Map is obsolete, global mappings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370732/automapper-says-mapper-map-is-obsolete-global-mappings)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson where is the info about this deprecated ?

Comment: Hi, if I put that code into VS2015 I will gget a deprecated warning. I will upload screenshot in a moment.

Comment: hi, just uploaded it. You will need to open up in another tab to see it better

Comment: @mybirthname interesting. will give it a go :)