# Automapper Map.CreateMap not used anymore?

Tags: c#, automapper-5

I'm using version 5.1.1.0 of AutoMapper.
Previously I was able to the following:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SchoolYearDetail, SchoolYearDto>();
```

But in the version 5.1.1.0 it doesn't exist anymore.
Can anyone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Previously `AutoMapper` was static as per your example, it now wants to be instantiated.

Link below is by the creator of `AutoMapper`
https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/01/21/removing-the-static-api-from-automapper/

Here is a snippet if that link stops working.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
  cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>();
});

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var source = new Source();
var dest = mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(source);
```

Plenty of other stackoverflow posts related to this:

[Automapper says Mapper.Map is obsolete, global mappings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370732/automapper-says-mapper-map-is-obsolete-global-mappings)

[AutoMapper Migrating from static API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35256008/automapper-migrating-from-static-api)

Hope that helps.